# forward eth0 traffic over tun0

Tags: vpn, openvpn, dhcp-server, eth0

I'm trying to setup a raspberry pi 3 as a vpn access point(?)

So far I have wlan0 configured to connect to a mobile hotspot, when this is connected openvpn connects to the vpn server.
This works fine, SSH'd in to the raspberry pi I can see anything I do on there goes over the tun0 interface.

I have now setup a **dhcp** server on eth0. This is working fine and hands out an IP address to the laptop when its hardwired. However I can't get any network access at all and ultimately want to send you all eth0 traffic over the tun0 interface.

I have enabled `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and also added the following iptables rules

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Okay,the setup does actually work. The iptables rules had not been saved after a reboot (Doh!)

Answer (score -1):

Openvpn tun is not intended to transport layer2 traffic as the one involved in DHCP setups.

Even if you manage to configure a DHCP relay on the other side (work around) you'll have then to set routes properly.

Comment: dhcp is only on the eth0 interface, its not being used over the tun0 connection